# Distribution key missing in tables greenplum database

Tags: greenplum

Need a Query to find the tables created with no distribution key in a database in Greenplum.

Answer (score 0):

```
select n.nspname,
    c.relname
from pg_class c
join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
join gp_distribution_policy d on c.oid = d.localoid
where c.relkind = 'r'
and d.attrnums is null;
```